An Error in Telethon lib; func: GetAuthorizationsRequest
I try for get all sessions list and terminate it in a telegram account using telethon library,
I use GetAuthorizationsRequest, resetAuthorizationsRequest funcs for do it but gave bellow Error:
at line 9:
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.BotMethodInvalidError: The API access for bot users is restricted. The method you tried to invoke cannot be executed as a bot (caused by GetAuthorizationsRequest)

I use this code:
from telethon.sync import functions, events
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient as tc2
bot = tc2('my_session_name', api_id='my_api_id', api_hash='my_api_hash')
bot.start(bot_token='my_token')
bot.on(events.NewMessage)
def answer(event):
    text = event.raw_text
    if text == 'del_sessions':
        result = bot(functions.account.GetAuthorizationsRequest())
        event.reply(str(result.stringify()))
        result = bot(functions.account.resetAuthorizationsRequest())
        event.reply(f'result: {result}')
bot.run_until_disconnected()

is it for telegram limits?

python 3.x - Telethon doesn't allow a bot to join a channel (The method you tried to invoke cannot be executed as a bot (caused by JoinChannelRequest) - Stack Overflow
